# Using \subfloat inside sidewaysfigure giving missing \item error

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats, rotating

I'm trying to produce a document where one page is in landscape, consisting of a graph and a table. Using the `lscape` package results in the graph being compressed horizontally, even if I set it to `50\textwidth` or something silly like that.

My the code looks like this (albeit in a longer document):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mytab}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
XX & YY \\
\hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}[counterclockwise]
\centering
\subfloat[ ][ Caption.... ]
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture.eps}} \\
\subfloat[ ][ Caption... ]{\mytab}
\caption{ Main caption }\label{Figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

When I proceed to compile using pdflatex the line

```
\subfloat[ ][ Caption... ]{\mytab}
```

errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

I can still get a PDF out of it, and it looks OK, but I'm wondering what's going wrong and why it's throwing the error? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TeX.SX !, i dont think if an error occured you still get the PDF output, are you sure it isnt an old version (compiled previously) ?

Comment: Yes - -I've even tried copying and pasting into a completely fresh .tex file in a different editor, and still got the error.

Comment: you're right it still provide the PDF even with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what happens, but the error is due to the `center` environment. However, you don't need any centering at all here, the `subfloat` is the width of its content, so you can remove it altogether. (If you need centering for some other context, use `\centering` before the tabular instead.

Hence, modify `\mytab` to this:

```
\newcommand{\mytab}{% <-- removes unwanted space
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
XX & YY \\
\hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
```

You also need to remove the optional argument to `sidewaysfigure`. Complete code and output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mytab}{%
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
XX & YY \\
\hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\ \hline
0000 -- 0000 & 00.00 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\subfloat[ ][ Caption.... ]
{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}} \\
\subfloat[ ][ Caption... ]{\mytab}
\caption{ Main caption }\label{Figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```